# Show warnings for methods longer than x lines in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-analysis, oclint

Is there a way how to check source code files (Objective C) and show warning for methods/functions that are longer than x lines (where the x can be configured). Something that can be integrated in Xcode would be great.

I have looked into these two following static analyzers for C/C++/ObjC code if they provide such functionality but I couldn't find anything mentioned in the documentation:

- http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org
- [http://oclint.org](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/rules/size.html?highlight=long%20method#longmethod) (longMethod rule)

Any ideas where to look further?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, looks like you could write an Xcode plugin to do that, sounds like it could be useful! I'll admit to not having done one before but I did find this [link](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/creating-an-xcode4-plugin/) as a starting point.

Comment: Heh, seems like that :) I've found that OClint does this kind of analysis: http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/rules/size.html?highlight=long%20method#longmethod